# Converting a recursive formula back to the original explicit formula?

Tags: math, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, recurrence

There is a generic formula Z^N = A(Z)^N+1 + B(Z)^N+1 . This formula is used to convert a given recursive function back to its original explicit form :

Recursive Formulas :

```
1) R(0) = 1, R(n) = (1/3) R(n-1), n = 1, 2, ...
2) P(0) = 1, P(1) = 1/3, P(n) = (4/3) P(n-1) - (1/3) P(n-2), n = 2, 3, ...
3) Q(0) = 1, Q(1) = 1/3, Q(n) = (10/3) Q(n-1) - Q(n-2), n = 2, 3, ...
```

Then, it suggests that "difference formulas" of the form :

```
2) P(n) = A(1/3^n) + B
3) Q(n) = A(1/3^n) + B * 3^n
```

represent the general solution.

Then the "difference functions" are to be substituted into the "recursive functions" to obtain root of A, B which completes the proof that the recursive function is indeed a representation of the original sequence {Xn} = {1/3^n} = 1, 1/3, 1/9, ...

My Question is where the difference formulas come from? I would appreciate a reference to the subject in any major text-book in calculus or numerical methods like Swokowski, Fink, or Chapra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a bit of freshman algebra.  Let's take example 3 for instance:

```
Q(n+2) = (10/3)Q(n+1) + (-1)Q(n)
Q(n+1) = (   1)Q(n+1) + ( 0)Q(n)
```

That second equation seems silly, but it allows us to write the following matrix equation:

```
[ Q(n+2) ]  = [ 10/3  -1 ][ Q(n+1) ]
[ Q(n+1) ]  = [    1   0 ][   Q(n) ]
```

This is the 2-dimensional analogue of a recurrence like `v(n+1) = a*v(n)` which has an easy solution `v(n) = a^n * v(0)`.  We can apply the same logic to our matrix equation to obtain:

```
[ Q(n+1) ] = [ 10/3  -1 ]^n [ 1/3 ]
[   Q(n) ] = [    1   0 ]   [   1 ]
```

Let's call that 2 x 2 matrix in the middle that we're raising to the nth power, `A`.Now how do we quickly compute powers of square matrices?  When they're diagonalizable, it's easy.  The eigenvalues of that 2x2 matrix are the roots of its characteristic polynomial:

```
det(A - xI) = (10/3 - x)(0 - x) - (1)(-1) = (x - 1/3)(x - 3)
```

This tells us that there's some invertible 2 x 2 matrix `P` (consisting of the eigenvectors of `A`) such that:

```
[ Q(n+1) ] = P [ 1/3  0 ]^n P^-1 [ 1/3 ]
[   Q(n) ] =   [   0  3 ]        [   1 ]
```

and so:

```
[ Q(n+1) ] = P [ 1/3^n    0 ] P^-1 [ 1/3 ]
[   Q(n) ] =   [     0  3^n ]      [   1 ]
```

From this we easily deduce that for some constants a and b:

```
Q(n) = a(1/3^n) + b(3^n)
```

We could explicitly figure out what they are by finding the eigenvectors of `A`, constructing the matrices `P` and `P^-1`, multiplying those three 2 x 2 matrices with the 2 x 1 vector on the right, and actually extracting the expression for `Q(n)` from that.  But it's easier to just look at the equation, realize that it'll result in something of the form `Q(n) = a(1/3^n) + b(3^n)` and actually just solve for `a` and `b` via back-substitution.

Comment: Thank you! I will be going through the steps once again with a pencil to make sure I get it. Could you also recommend a text-book on the subject and which chapter deals with such equations, because I'd like to practise through some drills.

Comment: Off the record, I am a student of computer science, but I am not good at mathematics. Any hints to become better at Maths.? I saw your blog is mainly about this idea.