# Conversion of a piecewise recursive function to a non-recursive function?

Tags: math, recursion, linear-algebra

My mathematical education only extends through calculus, and I found myself desiring to convert a piecewise recursive function to one without recursion.  Is there any way to do this without relying on pattern finding or similar brute force? (Is it even possible at all?)

Specifically, the function is: (for all whole numbers)
    f(0) = 1
    f(1) = 1
    f(2) = 2
    f(2n) = f(n) + f(n + 1) + n (for n > 1)
    f(2n + 1) = f(n - 1) + f(n) + 1 (for n >= 1)

I am aware of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814260/converting-a-recursive-formula-back-to-the-original-explicit-formula), but the answer involving matrices is beyond me.  If there is an explanation which requires less knowledge I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths, not about programming.

Comment: The `2n` makes this more difficult than the question you linked to.  You may have better luck once this question is migrated to math.se.

Comment: Your recurrence relation is much more complicated than the one from the post you linked.

First of all, your definition of elements does not rely on the previous elements but on `n/2`, so you won't be able to express the same recurrence with the same kind of matrix. Then, you have two formulas instead of a single one that is used for both even and uneven numbers. And finally, your definitions for 2 consecutive elements depend on 3 consecutive elements at `n/2` (even when using `{2n-1,2n}` or `{2n+1,2n+2}` instead of `{2n,2n+1}`).

Comment: @JohnDrake: since SO doesn't allow PMs, and you didn't leave any contact info on you profile, I'd just msg you here. I'd like to know if you've found the solution to your old/previous post http://quabr.com/28218639/find-expected-size-of-largest-weakly-connected-component; I'm facing the same problem, and don't know how to go about solving it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
According to your comment, you probably need some fast solution, not necessary interative one. I've checked recursion tree size - it is amazingly small - about 250 for 10^18 (roughly - `log2(M)` levels of recursion, about `3 + i` values on ith level). So I implemented recursion with memoization (a kind of DP), and this method works very fast for M = 2^80-1 ~ 10^24.

```
M = 1208944266358702884257791
Result = 24682648998311664639366438  
Map Size 321
```

Pseudocode:

```
  function F(Key)
     if Map.Contains(Key)then
        return Map.Value[Key]
      else
         usual recursion calls to get Result
         Map.Add(Key, Result)
```

**Old stuff** addressing the question literally:
If you don't want to discover general solution with advanced mathematics, you have to store calculated values. This is an example of non-recursive (iterative) function written in Delphi using queue as storage:

```
function ExoticFib(m: Integer): Integer;
var
  Q: TQueue<Integer>;
  n, fnm1, fn, fnp1, n2, n21: integer;
begin
  if m <= 3 then
    Exit(m + Ord(m = 0));  //return 1, 1, 2, 3

  Q := TQueue<Integer>.Create;
  Q.Enqueue(3);
  fn := 1;
  fnp1 := 2;

  for n := 2 to m div 2 do begin
    fnm1 := fn;      //forget the oldest value
    fn := fnp1;
    fnp1 := Q.Dequeue;  //here we have f(n-1), f(n), f(n+1)
    n2 := fn + fnp1 + n;
    Q.Enqueue(n2);
    n21 := fnm1 + fn + 1;
    Q.Enqueue(n21);
  end;

  if Odd(m) then // for m = 2k+1
    Result := n21
  else           // for m = 2k
    Result := n2;

  Q.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, but while I have a similar solution in python, it isn't fast enough, as I need to compute values up to n ~ 10^24.

Comment: Ouch, you probably need mathematical solution. Have you evaluated recursion call tree size?